# DataFrame column compare

Tags: python, regex, pandas, merge

I'm a beginner to python and am having a hard time finding documentation on how to fix a problem I've come across.

I need to know if the values in df1['id'] are in df2['id_list'] but hit a snag when I saw how the values were stored in df2

when I export the values which creates my "id_list" series, it prints out exactly as I've replicated below, and there in lies the rub. I'm not sure how to compare elements of series that are this different.

hope this makes sense and any help is appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = {'id':['xx00000001', 'xx00000002', 'xx00000003', 'xx00000004', 'xx00000005']
        }
df2={'id_list': ['text','xx00000001\r\nxx00000003\r\nxx00000004', 'xx00000003', 'xx00000004\r\ntext\r\nxx00000006', 'ss11111\r\ntext\r\nzz00000006\r\nxx00000005']
        }
desired = {'id':['xx00000001', 'xx00000002', 'xx00000003', 'xx00000004', 'xx00000005'],
        'id_list': ['text','xx00000001\r\nxx00000003\r\nxx00000004', 'xx00000003', 'xx00000004\r\ntext\r\nxx00000006', 'ss11111\r\ntext\r\nzz00000006\r\nxx00000005'],
        'located': [False, False, 'xx00000003', 'xx00000004', 'xx00000005']
        }


df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)
desired_df = pd.DataFrame(desired)
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(desired_df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of string problem, often list comprehensions are faster than built-in `pandas` string methods. You can do something like this:

```
desired_df = df1.join(df2)

desired_df['located'] = [i1 if i1 in i2 else False for i1, i2 in zip(df1['id'], df2['id_list']) ]

>>> desired_df
           id                                      id_list     located
0  xx00000001                                         text       False
1  xx00000002       xx00000001\r\nxx00000003\r\nxx00000004       False
2  xx00000003                                   xx00000003  xx00000003
3  xx00000004             xx00000004\r\ntext\r\nxx00000006  xx00000004
4  xx00000005  ss11111\r\ntext\r\nzz00000006\r\nxx00000005  xx00000005
```